# How to get value jquery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, jquery-autocomplete

I am using asp and getting data from other file for autocomplete. I tried many methods but i didn't get selected record's id value.

```
$().ready(function() {
function formatItem(row) {
    return row[0] + " (<strong>id: " + row[1] + "</strong>)";
}
function formatResult(row) {
    return row[0].replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, '');
}
$("#Datt").autocomplete("get_data.asp", {
    width: 600,
    selectFirst: true,
    scroll:false,
    max: 25,
    select: function( event, ui ) {}
    });

$("#Datt").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
    if (data)
        $(this).parent().next().find("Datt").val(data[1]);
        window.scrollTo(0,1)
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#OtherDatt").focus();
        });
});

});
```

And get_data.asp codes below...

```
<% 
qq = (Request.QueryString("q"))
set rsUrun=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rsUrun.Open "Select * from tbl_Customers WHERE Name like '%"  & qq & "%'  ORDER BY Name ASC", bag,1,3

If rsUrun.RecordCount > 0 Then 
i = 1
Sinirla = 10 
Do While Not rsUrun.EOF And i < (Sinirla + 1) %>

    <%=rsUrun("Adi")%> <%= vbCrlf  %>

    <%
    i = i + 1
    rsUrun.MoveNext
    Loop
    End If
    %>
```

Thanks for your helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in asp file. get_data.asp codes below.

```
If rsUrun.RecordCount > 0 Then
i = 1
Sinirla = 10


output = "["

Do While Not rsUrun.EOF And i < (Sinirla + 1) 

output = output & "{""id"":""" & rsUrun("ID") & """,""value"":""" & rsUrun("Adi") & """},"

i = i + 1

rsUrun.MoveNext
Loop

output=Left(output,Len(output)-1)
output = output & "]"
End If

Response.Write output
```